# Getting Required parameter missing error in CCAvenue

Tags: node.js, ccavenue

Actually am developing web application using mean stack, in this application am trying integrate ccavenue payment gateway using [node_ccavenue](https://github.com/nitishkumarsingh13/node-ccavenue) node package.

Below is my code:

```
    ccavenue.setMerchant("*****");
    ccavenue.setWorkingKey("***********************");
    ccavenue.setOrderId("WHIZ0001");
    ccavenue.setRedirectUrl("http://localhost:7777/login");
    ccavenue.setOrderAmount('1000.00');

    var param = {
                  billing_cust_address: 'Chennai', 
                  billing_cust_name: 'Kalaiselvan',
                  billing_cust_country: 'India',
                  billing_cust_state: 'Tamilnadu',
                  billing_cust_city: 'Chennai',
                  billing_zip: '600056',
                  billing_cust_tel: '9003321521',
                  billing_cust_email: 'kalai131192@gmail',
                  delivery_cust_name: 'Kalaiselvan',
                  delivery_cust_country: 'India',
                  delivery_cust_state: 'Tamilnadu',
                  delivery_cust_city: 'Chennai',
                  delivery_zip: '600056',
                  delivery_cust_tel: '9003321521',
                  delivery_cust_email: 'kalai131192@gmail',
         };
         ccavenue.setOtherParams(param); //Set Customer Info 

// Server url where you want to send data to ccavenue 
router.get('/make-payment', function(req, res) {
    ccavenue.makePayment(res); // It will redirect to ccavenue payment 
});

router.post('/redirect-url', function response(req, res) {
    var data = ccavenue.paymentRedirect(req); //It will get response from ccavenue payment. 
    console.log(data);
    if(data.isCheckSumValid === true && data.AuthDesc == 'Y') {
        console.log('Success' + res);
        // Success 
        // Your code 
     } else if(data.isCheckSumValid === true && data.AuthDesc == 'N') {
            console.log('UnSuccess' + res);
        // Unuccessful 
        // Your code 
    } else if(data.isCheckSumValid === true && data.AuthDesc == 'B') {
        // Batch processing mode 
        // Your code 
    } else {
        // Illegal access 
        // Your code 
    }   
});
```

while am trying this am getting error as 
[image: error-image]

Help me to sort out this, am stuck with this, help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to [Acewebworld](https://www.acewebworld.com/blog/whmcs-ccavenue-m-c-p-g-module/)

> **Error Code**: 90,  **Explanation**: The Encryption key you entered in WHMCS
>   gateway module setting is not correct.  Kindly note that, you will get
>   a unique encryption key for a unique URL setup in your CCAvenue MCPG
>   gateway settings API page (if you have more than one URL setup there).